# Scipy interpolate 2D with one value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I would like to interpolate X, Y, Z in Python and return the interpolated results X, Y with z.  For example

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
z = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

i = interp2d(x, y, z)
i(1, 2)
Out: array([ 1.5])
```

So, here, the interp2d object takes X and Y to get Z.  I would like to give Z to get X and Y.  I think I might need a spline function.

Comment: the problem is that there will be many cases were more than one possibility for `x` and `y` will exist for a given `z` value

Comment: Not for what I have in mind.  Plus, that shouldn't be a problem, it should return a list.

Comment: Are you looking for 2 one-dimensional interpolations?  In your example if you give Z=1.5 would you want Out: array([1.5, 1.5])?

Comment: No, @jdborg, it cannot return a list. Because in 2D there can be infinite number of points that satisfy your condition. Imagine that you have `f(z)=x**2+y**2`. The solution you get for `f(x,y)==2.` is a circle. How should those points be returned?